# how to get container host machine ip address and container name in EKS

Tags: docker, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have a docker file and using that i have build the image and then used EKS service to launch the containers. Now in my application for logging purpose I am taking environment variables like "container_instance" and "ec2_instance_id" and logging it so that I can see in Elastic Search from which container or host ec2 machine this log got generated.

How can I set these 2 data when I start my container in environment variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Kubernetes Pod spec, you can use the [downward API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/) to inject some of this information.  For example, to get the node's Kubernetes node name, you can set

```
env:
  - name: MY_NODE_NAME
    valueFrom:
      fieldRef:
        fieldPath: spec.nodeName
```

The node name is typically a hostname for the node ([this example in the EKS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/launch-workers.html) shows the EC2 internal hostnames, for example).  You can't easily get things like an EC2 instance ID at a per-pod level.

You also might configure logging globally at a cluster level.  The Kubernetes documentation includes [a packaged setup to route logs to Elasticsearch and Kibana](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/logging-elasticsearch-kibana/).  The example shown there includes only the pod name in the log message metadata, but you should be able to reconfigure the underlying [fluentd](https://fluentd.io/) to include additional host-level metadata.